# Is it possible to use $http of AngularJS as stand alone application?

Tags: xmlhttprequest

[$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is a nice aspect of AngularJS. But can we use it without AngularJS?

For example:

```
<script src="LIBRARY/http.js"></js>

var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

The intention is to use $http without AngularJS. (Usage example copied from the documentation.)

Comment: AngularJS code base it at: https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/

Answer (score 2):

I haven't come across standalone http package provided by angular but axios is another library that is similar to angularJs http module. Both axios and http are promise based http clients. I'd say using axios would be better than bringing entire angularJs library.

https://github.com/axios/axios
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: https://reactjs.org/community/data-fetching.html seems to list few solutions including axios.

Comment: I personally like axios, needle and super agent. Axios is the most similar to angular http module. See the docs for all of them.

Comment: if using rollup for bundling, see https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1259